# terminal based chat app giving the error: 'invalid literal for int() with base 10:' when trying to return messages from other clients to a client

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, socket.io

This is happening when the message broadcast to other clients by the server is longer than the username length. Does anyone have a fix? 
Please see my code below for both the chat server and the client. I believe the error is being caused by line 28 or 34 of the client code but do not know how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Server code:

```
import socket
import select

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 65432
HEADER_LENGTH = 100

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # Creating socket object
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)  # Allowing the same address to be reused

s.bind((host, port))  # Binding the socket to the IP address and port number
s.listen()  # Listening for incoming connections

print(f'Listening for incoming connections on IP address {host}.')

client_socket_list = [s]  # List for appending connected sockets to for select to keep track of

clients = {}  # Dict for informing other clients in a better way than just socket info who they are

# Defining a function for receiving messages from client sockets
def receiving_messages(client_socket):
    try:
        msg_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)  # Getting the message header
        # If we do not get any data for the message header then we need code to handle this
        if not len(msg_header):
            return False
        else:
            msg_length = int(msg_header.decode("utf-8"))  # Converting the header to a length
            return {"header": msg_header, "data": client_socket.recv(msg_length)}  # Returning      the data from the message
    except:
        return False

while True:
# Below socket is taking in parameters (1, 2, 3) (1) the read list(things we want to read in)(2)     the sockets we want to write (3) sockets with possible error
    read_sockets, _, exception_sockets = select.select(client_socket_list, [], client_socket_list)

    for x in read_sockets:  # x = socket that has been notified of chat room entry (iterating over     sockets with info to be read)
        if x == s:  # Handling for a new connection
            client_socket, client_address = s.accept()  # Accepting a new connection, getting     unique client socket and address
            user = receiving_messages(client_socket)  # User data

            if user is False:  # Handling for a disconnection
                 continue

            client_socket_list.append(client_socket)  # Adding the new client socket to the list

            clients[client_socket] = user  # Adding the user information to the clients dictionary

            print(f"New connection accepted from IP: {client_address[0]} Port: {client_address[1]}     username: {user['data'].decode('utf-8')}")
        else:
            message = receiving_messages(x)  # If the socket is not the server socket then we have a message to read

            if message is False:
                print(f"Connection closed from {clients[x]['data'].decode('utf-8')}")
                client_socket_list.remove(x)  # Removing the socket on which the connection has been closed from the list of clients
                del clients[x]  # Removing the client info from the dict
                continue

            user = clients[x]
            print(f"Received message from {user['data'].decode('utf-8')}: {message['data'].decode('utf-8')}")

            # Now sharing the message with all other users in the chatroom
            for client_socket in clients:  # Iterating over all connecting clients
                if client_socket != x:  # Stopping the message being sent out to the client that     sent the message

                    client_socket.send(user['header'] + user['data'] + message['header'] + message     ['data'])  # Sending the message from client X to all other clients
    # Removing users if there is a socket error causing unexpected connection closure
    for x in exception_sockets:
        client_socket_list.remove(x)
        del clients[x]
```

Client code:

```
import socket
import errno
import sys

HEADER_LENGTH = 100
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 65432

my_username = input('Username: ')  # User input of username (Not encoded in utf-8 bytes)

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect((host, port))
client_socket.setblocking(False)  # Telling the recv method not to block

# Server expects the first message to be a username input by the user
username = my_username.encode('utf-8') # Encoding the user into bytes to send
username_header = f'{len(username):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}'.encode('utf-8')  # Defining a variable         username_header and stating that the length of the username must be aligned to the     left within the specified length set by HEADER_LENGTH

client_socket.send(username_header + username) # Sending client username info to the server

# Sending messages
while True:
    message = input(f'{my_username} : ')  # my_username used so it is not already encoded when     using it here to attach the message the user inputs

    # Sending messages and handling for an empty input i.e. no message input
    if message:
         message = message.encode('utf-8')  # Encoding the message into utf-8 bytes ready to send     to the server
""" line 28 """message_header = f'{len(message):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}'.encode('utf-8')  #     Defining a variable message_header containing the information that the length of the message must be aligned to the left within the length of the username header
        client_socket.send(message_header + message) # Encoded message now sent along with the     message length info
    try:
        while True:
            # Receiving messages from other clients

""" line 34 """username_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)

            if not len(username_header):  # Handling for an error where the username header length      is not what it should be
                print('connection closed by the server')
                sys.exit()  # System closing the connection due to no more messages

            # Getting the username of the other client that sent the last message
            username_length = int(username_header.decode('utf-8').strip())  # Possibly username length
            username = client_socket.recv(username_length).decode('utf-8')

             # Getting the message from the server that the other client has sent
            message_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
            message_length = int(message_header.decode('utf-8').strip())
            message = client_socket.recv(username_length).decode('utf-8')

            print(f'{username}: {message}')  # Printing the message from the other client along with that clients username

    # Preventing consistent errors being raised causing issue within the program as within a non-    blocking connection an error will continually be raised when no messages are coming through etc
    except IOError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.EAGAIN and e.errno != errno.EWOULDBLOCK and e.errno !=     errno.WASEWOULDBLOCK:
            print('Expecting message but not receiving ', str(e))
            sys.exit()
        continue

    # Handling for all other unexpected errors that may occur
    except Exception as e:
        print('General error ', str(e))
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: please post the full traceback

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-b71684796235>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/hassallj/Documents/Python Scripts/Chat_Server_and_Client/Practice/CAC.py', wdir='C:/Users/hassallj/Documents/Python Scripts/Chat_Server_and_Client/Practice')

  File "C:\Users\hassallj\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

Comment: File "C:\Users\hassallj\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/hassallj/Documents/Python Scripts/Chat_Server_and_Client/Practice/CAC.py", line 61, in <module>
    sys.exit()

SystemExit

Comment: Error appears to occur when message_length > username_length